# flask runtime.lastError and 404 serving icons

Tags: python, vue.js, flask

What im trying to fix is a flask webserver serving vuejs on a raspberry pi

So i did have this working but then i went ahead and cleaned my code cause i made the frontend using components from a diffrent project and somehow broke it getting 2 errors but both happen twice

first one is runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Recieving end does not exist

second one is Failed to load resource basically a 404 when loading an image

im thinking the first error caused the 2nd as the static files come from `npm run build` and the frontend does work in visual studio

vue router

```
routes: [
    {
      name: 'local',
      path: '/local',
      component: () => import('@/components/comp/local')
    }
]
```

how i render index

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='web/static',
            template_folder='web/templates')
@app.route('/local')
def index():
         return render_template("index.html")
```

i can reach the routes, but cant figure out how to get to the static files

i wont add raspberry-pi as the autostart and chromium opening isnt a problem just the fact that the frontend dosent show up

Comment: well i do see a --> on the page migth be something from vue

Comment: Not sure what was wrong when i turned it on today there was a diffrent error that went away after rebuilding the frontend :d